# The slice does not copy the list items, but the link to the list

Tags: python, list, loops, copy

```
matrix_a = [[5, 0.9, 0.3, 0.2],
        [0.2, 8, 0.7, 0.5],
        [1, 0.3, 5.5, 0.4],
        [0.2, 0.5, 0.7, 6]]
 matrix_d = [7,
        9,
        -5,
        6]
def kramer_method(matrix, solution, determinant):

for i in range(4):
    temp_matrix = matrix[:]
    for t in range(4):
        temp_matrix[t][i] = solution[t]
    print(temp_matrix)
print(id(temp_matrix) == id(matrix))
return
kramer_method(matrix_a,matrix_d,determinant)
```

result:

```
[[7, 0.9, 0.3, 0.2], [9, 8, 0.7, 0.5], [-5, 0.3, 5.5, 0.4], [6, 0.5, 0.7, 6]]
[[7, 7, 0.3, 0.2], [9, 9, 0.7, 0.5], [-5, -5, 5.5, 0.4], [6, 6, 0.7, 6]]
[[7, 7, 7, 0.2], [9, 9, 9, 0.5], [-5, -5, -5, 0.4], [6, 6, 6, 6]]
[[7, 7, 7, 7], [9, 9, 9, 9], [-5, -5, -5, -5], [6, 6, 6, 6]]
False
```

The quetion is: why is the temp_matrix list not taking the original matrix values ​​at the start of the loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking a slice of a list does copy the list. It does what is known as a shallow copy. This means that while `temp_matrix` is a copy of the original list, it does not copy the elements. So if you did something like `temp_matrix.append([1,2,3])`, it would not change `matrix`. Since it does not copy the elements, if you modify one of those `temp_matrix[0].append(5)`, it would modify both `temp_matrix` and `matrix` since it is modifying the lists inside which were not copied.

What you will want to do is use the [copy](https://docs.python.org/3/library/copy.html) module. Specifically, you will want to `import copy`, and rather than use `temp_matrix = matrix[:]`, you would use `temp_matrix = copy.deepcopy(matrix)`. That page about the copy module also explains a bit more about what a deep copy is needed over a shallow copy as you had originally.

Comment: But is this shallow copy happens, because I have lists in my "matrix" list? Because if I do slice with simple list of elements, it will work in right way without copying adress.
Thanks a lot for the answer!

Comment: Exactly, when you slice a list, it does not copy the elements, just a reference to them. Numbers can't be changed so you don't notice with just a list of numbers or strings, or other immutable elements. But when you copy lists, they can change so you would notice this issue when you modify one of them. Good luck with your projct!

Comment: @GeorgeGray it *always* works the same way regardless of type, just that *certain types are immutable* so they cannot be changed